# Google App Engine Image API inconsistencies

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have uploaded a 8MB, 7296 x 5472 pixels image to GAE using the blobstore upload API. When displayed in it's original size (by appending =s0 at the end of the URL) it shows fine, the size and resolution is correct, same for the default URL without appending anything (512 width). However, when resizing to 1920 the image size jumps to 33.45 MB (=s1920). You can check this yourselves.

The image URL: http://lh5.ggpht.com/8kuSpgSom_kMZ13laFfpuC8UGWu_DGQXOzLKR213jzk3s9rEOC3483bcyfJ1PHfPyRU38GU5faJ7BLbGgSkx2P4ijg

Append =s0 and =s1920 to it.

I checked this in both Firefox and Chrome, same results. The page seems to keep loading even after the image has been fully displayed.

BTW: isn't the maximum allowed length 1600? why is 1920 even working?

Note: the image is not mine. You can find the original image [here](http://www.meetup.com/KAYAK-GULF-NATURE-COAST-CENTRAL-FLORIDA-RIVERS/photos/7429762/):

Comment: you are right. the max allowed side when resizing should be 1600, but i do not get a 33.45mb image when resizing to 1920. i get a 1920x1440px image and 1.26mb for all browsers.

Comment: I've tested this on both linux and windows on two different systems, two different ISPs and I get the same results. Maybe it's the location? Maybe some edge location is broken. I'm in the UK.

Comment: that could be an answer but its kind of hard to prove it. im accessing the image from nyc.

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work in 3 European countries.